# WPF MenuItem template makes subitem background transparent

Tags: wpf, xaml

I want to modify the **TopLevelHeader** to not display any borders and hover effects. To do so I've overwritten the default MenuItem style using the following MSDN example:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747082(v=vs.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747082%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

My problem is that with this style the subItems are displayed with a transparent background. I've also tried to use the style form aero.normalcolor.xaml but the problem remains, the subItems have a transparent background.

The relevant part:

```
<Style x:Key="SimpleMenuItemBasic" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">    
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Role" Value="TopLevelHeader">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                            <Border Name="Border" >
                                <Grid>
                                    <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header" RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
                                    <Popup Name="Popup" 
                                           Placement="Bottom" 
                                           IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsSubmenuOpen}" 
                                           AllowsTransparency="True" 
                                           Focusable="False" 
                                           PopupAnimation="Fade">
                                        <Border Name="SubmenuBorder" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" 
                                                Background="{DynamicResource WindowBackgroundBrush}"
                                                BorderBrush="{DynamicResource SolidBorderBrush}"
                                                BorderThickness="1">
                                            <ItemsPresenter KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle"
                                                                                KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Cycle"
                                                                                Margin="0,0,0,1"
                                                                                SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                                        </Border>
                                    </Popup>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsSuspendingPopupAnimation" Value="true">
                                    <Setter TargetName="Popup" Property="PopupAnimation" Value="None"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true">
                                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource NormalBrush}"/>
                                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger SourceName="Popup" Property="Popup.AllowsTransparency" Value="True">
                                    <Setter TargetName="SubmenuBorder" Property="CornerRadius" Value="0,0,4,4"/>
                                    <Setter TargetName="SubmenuBorder" Property="Padding" Value="0,0,0,3"/>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource DisabledForegroundBrush}"/>
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="Grid.IsSharedSizeScope" Value="true"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

And the usage example:

```
<Menu>
    <MenuItem Header="menuItem1" Style="{StaticResource SimpleMenuItemBasic}">
        <MenuItem Header="subitem1" />
        <MenuItem Header="subitem2" />
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

Answer (score 2):

Step 1 - Open Blend for Visual Studio (Previously Expression Blend)

Blend for Visual Studio is the tool for styling. It is awesome and everyone who is styling should use it more often.

With Visual Studio 2012 and 2013, you should get Blend with your MSDN Subscription.

Step 2 - Open your solution in Blend.

Step 3 - Right-click on your MenuItem and choose Edit Template | Edit a copy.

This creates a copy of the default style that is used. It creates a copy of the entire style. This will be a lot of Xaml. I usually create this in a separate ResourceDictionary file but for this example, I will put it right in the MainWindow Resources.

Step 4 - Comment out the highlight stuff in the default style that affects the Top MenuItem.

Step 5 - Only keep what you changed.

We only needed to comment out a single trigger in one control template. So lets remove all the extra except for that ControlTemplate.

Note: I left what I commented out so you can see it.

Now when you highlight the top MenuItems, nothing happens. But when you right-click and the submenu pops up, everything is the same as normal.

Here is the resulting Xaml. Hope this helps you.

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="StackOverflowMenuTransparent.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">    
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <!--<SolidColorBrush x:Key="MenuItem.Highlight.Background" Color="#3D26A0DA"/>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MenuItem.Highlight.Border" Color="#FF26A0DA"/>-->
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Menu.Disabled.Foreground" Color="#FF707070"/>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Menu.Static.Border" Color="#FF999999"/>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Menu.Static.Background" Color="#FFF0F0F0"/>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Menu.Static.Separator" Color="#FFD7D7D7"/>
            <Geometry x:Key="Checkmark">F1 M 10.0,1.2 L 4.7,9.1 L 4.5,9.1 L 0,5.2 L 1.3,3.5 L 4.3,6.1L 8.3,0 L 10.0,1.2 Z</Geometry>
            <ControlTemplate x:Key="NoHoverMenuItemTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                <Border x:Name="templateRoot" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="Icon" ContentSource="Icon" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="16" Margin="3" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="16"/>
                        <Path x:Name="GlyphPanel" Data="{StaticResource Checkmark}" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Margin="3" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" ContentSource="Header" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                        <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="true" Focusable="false" IsOpen="{Binding IsSubmenuOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.MenuPopupAnimationKey}}" Placement="Bottom" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=templateRoot}">
                            <Border x:Name="SubMenuBorder" BorderBrush="{StaticResource Menu.Static.Border}" BorderThickness="1" Background="{StaticResource Menu.Static.Background}" Padding="2">
                                <ScrollViewer x:Name="SubMenuScrollViewer" Style="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=MenuScrollViewer, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type FrameworkElement}}}">
                                    <Grid RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                                        <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="0">
                                            <Rectangle x:Name="OpaqueRect" Fill="{Binding Background, ElementName=SubMenuBorder}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=SubMenuBorder}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=SubMenuBorder}"/>
                                        </Canvas>
                                        <Rectangle Fill="{StaticResource Menu.Static.Separator}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="29,2,0,2" Width="1"/>
                                        <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsPresenter" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="true" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Cycle"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </ScrollViewer>
                            </Border>
                        </Popup>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSuspendingPopupAnimation" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="PopupAnimation" TargetName="PART_Popup" Value="None"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="Icon" Value="{x:Null}">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="GlyphPanel" Value="Visible"/>
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Icon" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <!--<Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource MenuItem.Highlight.Background}"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource MenuItem.Highlight.Border}"/>
                    </Trigger>-->
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="{StaticResource Menu.Disabled.Foreground}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="GlyphPanel" Value="{StaticResource Menu.Disabled.Foreground}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" SourceName="SubMenuScrollViewer" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" TargetName="OpaqueRect" Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, ElementName=SubMenuScrollViewer}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" TargetName="OpaqueRect" Value="{Binding HorizontalOffset, ElementName=SubMenuScrollViewer}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Menu Grid.Row="0">
            <MenuItem Header="_File" Template="{DynamicResource NoHoverMenuItemTemplate}" >         
                <MenuItem Header="_Open" />
                <MenuItem Header="_Save" />
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="_Help" Template="{DynamicResource NoHoverMenuItemTemplate}" >         
                <MenuItem Header="_About" />
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="1" AcceptsReturn="True">
            <TextBox.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>

                </ContextMenu>
            </TextBox.ContextMenu>
        </TextBox>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```